# Unix command for list all the files by grouping and sorting by file type and name

Tags: unix

There are lots of files in a directory and output to be group and sort like below,first exe files 
    without any file extension,then sql files ending with "body",then sql files ending with "spec",then 
    other sql files.then "sh" then "txt" files.

```
 abc
 1_spec.sql
 1_body.sql
 2_body.sql
 other.sql
 a1.sh
 a1.txt

find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! -name "*.*" 
find . -type f  -name "*body*.sql" 
find . -type f  -name "*spec*.sql"

Getting difficult to combine all and sorting group with order.
```

Answer (score 0):

with `ls`, `grep` and `sort` you could do something like this script I hacked together:

```
#!/bin/sh

ls | grep -v '\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*$' | sort
ls | grep '_body.sql$' | sort
ls | grep '_spec.sql$' | sort
ls | grep -vE '_body.sql$|_spec.sql$' | grep '.sql$' | sort
ls | grep '.sh$' | sort
ls | grep '.txt$' | sort
```

normal `ls`:

```
$ ls -1
1_body.sql
1_spec.sql
2_body.sql
a1.sh
a1.txt
abc
bar.sql
def
foo.sh
other.sql
script
$
```

sorting script:

```
$ ./script
abc
def
script
1_body.sql
2_body.sql
1_spec.sql
bar.sql
other.sql
a1.sh
foo.sh
a1.txt
$
```